# cannot print javascript array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var menu_items = 0;

$(".trueol").each(function(){

    menu_items = menu_items + 1;

});

var product_price = new Array(menu_items);

var product_name = new Array(menu_items);

        $(".price").each(function(){
        var i = 0;
            product_price[i] = $(this).data("p");
            document.write(product_price[i]); /*Inner document.write*/
            i++;
        });
         document.write(product_price[2]); /*Outer document.write*/

        $(".menu_product").each(function(){
            var j = 0;
            product_name[j] = $(this).text();
            document.write(product_name[j]); /*Inner document.write*/
            j++;
        });

           document.write(product_name[2]); /* Outer document.write */
```

Here, the inner document.write works just fine but outer ones print undefined.
P.S menu_items has a value of 4 after iterating. What's the problem ?

Comment: It's a scope issue. product_name is correctly not defined inside that function. You need to read up on variable scope. :)

Comment: i think u should put var i=0 and var j=0 out of the loop. otherwise it will always save data in array at position 0 no increment

Comment: @i-Conica: the variable is defined, otherwise the op would get a reference error.

Comment: Show the complete code... And Fiddle would be better...!!

Comment: Yeah I looked again, it's either been edited or it's too early in the morning for me. :)

Comment: by mistake i initialized i and j inside the loop which resulted in resetting their value at each iteration. thanks @mayankchaturvedi

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you reset your counter at every single iteration (`var i = 0` and `var j = 0`).

Just use `.each()` with an index.

```
// Arrays for your values
var product_price = [];
var product_name = [];

$(".price").each(function(index) {
    product_price.push($(this).data("p"));
    document.write(product_price[index]); /*Inner document.write*/
});

$(".menu_product").each(function(index) {
    product_name.push($(this).text());
    document.write(product_name[index]); /*Inner document.write*/
});

// Outer write
document.write(product_name[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers explaining using the `each` iterator's index are correct, but you're overcomplicating the issue.  You can simply push the values onto the end of the arrays and miss out any counting...

```
var product_price = [];
var product_name = [];

$(".price").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).data("p");
    product_price.push(value);
    document.write(value); /*Inner document.write*/
});
document.write(product_price[2]); /*Outer document.write*/

$(".menu_product").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    product_name.push(value);
    document.write(value); /*Inner document.write*/
});

document.write(product_name[2]); /* Outer document.write */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Should you need to know the number of items in the arrays at any point, just use

```
product_price.length
```

or

```
product_name.length
```

One other hint.  I assume you're using `document.write` as a method of outputting data for debugging purposes.  Try using `console.log("text");` instead, and then open the browser console (usually F12 and go to the console tab).

Comment: You're welcome - it's much better to use that than pollute the DOM with something that doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try tro use `push()` as in every iteration your counter sets to `0`,

```
var product_name = [],
    product_price = [];

$(".price").each(function(){
    t = $(this).data("p");
    document.write(t); /*Inner document.write*/
    product_price.push(t); // use push here
});
document.write(product_price[2]); /*Outer document.write*/

$(".menu_product").each(function(){
     t = $(this).text();
     document.write(t); /*Inner document.write*/
     product_name.push(t); // use push here
});
document.write(product_name[2]); /* Outer document.write */
```